# C++: Is it defined behavior to typedef nested type with same name?

Tags: c++, typedef

the code:

```cpp
class Global
{
public:
    static const char *name() {return "Global";}
};
typedef Global T_Outter;

class Outter
{
public:
    typedef T_Outter O_Outter; // <= <1>
    typedef Outter T_Outter; // <= <2>
    static const char *name() {return "Outter";}
    static void test() {printf("self: %s, outter: %s\n", name(), O_Outter::name());}

    class Inner
    {
    public:
        typedef T_Outter O_Outter;
        typedef Inner T_Outter;
        static const char *name() {return "Inner";}
        static void test() {printf("self: %s, outter: %s\n", name(), O_Outter::name());}
    };
};

Outter::test();
Outter::Inner::test();
// output:
// self: Outter, outter: Global
// self: Inner, outter: Outter
```

what I want to do:

- obtain nested class info without knowing it's actual parent class or scope
- the `typedef`s would be generated by macros, with the tricks, there's no need to manually "bind" `Outter` and `Inner`'s relationship, it's done by `typedef` automatically

here's the question:

- is it defined behavior in the above code?

  - `<1>` and `<2>` with same `T_Outter` name
  - `Outter::O_Outter` equals to `Global`
  - `Outter::Inner:O_Outter` equals to `Outter`
- is it portable to use the trick?

Comment: Which of the three typedefs of `T_Outter` are you worried about? The last? Both of the ones not at namespace scope? All three?

Comment: What is this trying to achieve? Obfuscation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not allowed to change meaning of a global name inside a class after it was used unqualified in the class definition. The program is ill-formed, NDR.

See [[basic.scope.class]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.class#2):

> A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of `S`. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

[Live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tx8zzs) with GCC 10:

> `error: declaration of 'typedef class Outter Outter::T_Outter' changes meaning of 'T_Outter' [-fpermissive]`

A possible workaround is to qualify it:

```
class Outter {
public:
    typedef ::T_Outter O_Outter;
    typedef Outter T_Outter;   // OK
    . . .
```

Comment: Deleted my answer - this is correct. The underlying reason here is that the class methods  must be compiled after all class members are declared. Practically this requires the name lookup to give consistent results.